# Free bug tracker with guest support

Tags: web-apps, issue-tracker

I'm looking for an online bug tracker/issue tracker etc...

There are tonnes of them online but I need a specific thing that I can't find on any of the ones on google.
I need it to have to ability to post bugs without having to sign up for an account. Public bug reporting. Like a contact form that creates a bug ticket and adds it to the list.
We have a large amount of users that don't have any sort of email or account associated with them and we need to give them a way to report bugs without them having to sign up.

Any ideas?

Apps I've already tried, the problem is that they require creating an account:

- Jira
- Mantisbt
- trello
- Github
- Axosoft
- Redmine
- Bugzilla

Comment: You should probably list the software you've already eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Google Form, with the result being fed into a Google Spreadsheet. Users will not have to sign in if you specify that 'anyone with the link' can access the form.

You could also make the resulting spreadsheet publicly readable, to avoid people filling duplicates.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Didn't even think of using Google docs. That's a great idea.